# How to print 10 prime numbers on each table row

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a JavaScript that prints the prime numbers between 1 and 999 in a table that consists of 10 columns.

Once the counter variable reaches a value of 10 (meaning that 10 cells have been added to the current row ) then I  print `</tr><tr>` to start a new row and reset the variable to 0.
I have been trying and I managed to print the prime numbers in the table but now to create a new row after every 10 columns is where I am failings.

Any assistance will be appreciated .

Below is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            document.write("<table border='1'>");
            document.write("<tr>");
            for(n = 0 ; n < 1000; n++){
                var x=1;
                if(n==0 || n==1) x=0;
                for(i=2;i<n;i++)
                {
                    if(n%i==0)
                    {
                        x=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(x==1)
                {
                    document.write("<td>"); 
                    // if prime print the numbers 
                    document.write(n);
                    document.write("</td>");
                }
                else
                { 
                // if not prime number do nothing 
                }
            }  
            document.write("</table>");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This smells suspiciously like homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed your `else` part and I used `ok` to count the prime numbers.
If this counter is 10, 20, 30, ... ( `ok % 10 === 0 && ok > 0` ), then I close the actual row using `<\tr>` and I open the new row using `<tr>`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript">
            document.write("<table border='1'><tr>");
            var ok = 0 ;
            for(n = 0 ; n < 1000; n++) {
                var x=1;
                if(n==0 || n==1) x=0;
                for(i=2 ; i<n ; i++) {
                    if(n%i==0) {
                        x=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(x==1) {
                  if ( ok % 10 === 0 && ok > 0 ) {
                     document.write("</tr><tr>");
                  }
                  document.write("<td>"); 
                  document.write(n);
                  document.write("</td>");
                  ok++;
                }
            }  
            document.write("</tr></table>");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not knw what to say but to me u are a star

Answer (score 1):

Create the counter before the loop:

```
var cnt = 0;
```

Before writing out the cell, increase the counter and check the value:

```
if(x==1)
{
  cnt++;
  if (cnt == 10)
  {
    cnt = 0;
    document.write("</tr><tr>");
  }
  document.write("<td>"); 
  document.write(n);
  document.write("</td>");
}
```

Also, you forgot to close the last row before closing the table:

```
document.write("</tr>");
document.write("</table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sieve algorithm with 1000 for example

```
function getPrimes(max) {
    var sieve = [], i, j, primes = [];
    for (i = 2; i <= max; ++i) {
        if (!sieve[i]) {
            // i has not been marked -- it is prime
            primes.push(i);
            for (j = i << 1; j <= max; j += i) {
                sieve[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

And then

```
for(n = 0 ; n < 100; n++){
    if(n % 10 == 0)
```

Comment: prime numbers are generated clearly but how to break that table every after 10 columns is my prob

Comment: Loop over them and take mod 10 of index